# Проверка пунктуации в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Хотел бы узнать: правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?

"Наверное, Анна торопится: она ушла не сказав ни слова".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Извините, Артём, но я специально не правила точку внутри кавычек, чтобы была возможность указать автору на эту ошибку.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: не подумал даже об этом, простите. Многим придётся на это указывать (распространённая ошибка). Почему-то это особенно сильно режет глаз, и, когда об этом отдельно вопрос не стоит, мне бы очень не хотелось, чтобы это оставалось. Но если большинство станут на Вашу сторону, конечно, надо делать по-Вашему. Жалко, опрос нельзя провести.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: проблема ещё и в том, что такие ошибки множатся, попадая в ответы. То есть опытные люди (отвечающие) могут поправить орфографию, правильно расставить запятые, другие знаки, а на точку перед кавычками закрыть глаза, и так и пойдёт это кочевать. (Я вот сегодня поправил ещё одну такую ошибку, но указал автору на неё в комментарии, учитывая Ваше замечание.)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я думаю, если человек спрашивает про пунктуацию конкретной фразы, то править её в вопросе нельзя. Иначе можно доправиться до того, что вопрос превратиться в фарс. Смысл вопроса теряется.

Comment: @behemothus: да, я это понимаю, просто кавычки — это уже оболочка фразы, а спрашивает он в первую очередь о её сути, т. е. о ней как о написанной без кавычек, но невольно делает ошибку ещё и в них. Скажите, behemothus (и Римма тоже), а вы не согласны на то, чтобы я правил (**только (!)** порядок точки и кавычек, больше ничего и не хочу) и при этом в комментарии к вопросу писал, что автор написал не в том порядке, а правильно наоборот?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой То есть вы считаете, что вопрос в отношении этой точки не стоял?  Мммм... Может быть, конечно, но тогда это все это надо донести до автора в явном виде. А то получается, что у закавыченной фразы и её оригиналом есть разница в орфографии, а это слишком сложно объяснить в рамках такого "цеольного" вопроса.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *а вы не согласны на то, чтобы я правил* - я отчасти проникся вашей идее относительно оболочки, не знаю, может и стоит править, но этот момент надо довести до спрашивающего в явном виде. А насчет правки... Лучше всего, наверное, заменить кавычки на цитату, как она тут оформляется в соответствии с общепринятыми приемами. там эта точка окажется в нужном месте.

Comment: Мне казалось, что не стояло о ней вопроса, но я могу и ошибаться, конечно. А прокомментировать первым или одним из первых комментариев — это явный вид? Рад, что прониклись! :) *А прокомментировать первым или одним/ - ну да, о том и речь.* Отлично! (Правлю этот комментарий, чтобы не разводить новых, а то много уже.)

Comment: *А прокомментировать первым или одним...* - ну да, о том и речь.

Answer (score 2):

*Наверное, Анна торопится: она ушла,  **не сказав ни слова**.*

1) **Это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение),** между частями БСП  отношения **пояснительные** (объясняется предположение автора).

2) Вводное слово ***наверное*** обособляется.

3) Деепричастные обороты ***не сказав ни слова, не говоря ни слова*** обособляются практически всегда и в любой позиции. Стать обстоятельством образа действия у них, как правило, не получается, поэтому они **обозначают добавочное действие**.

**Почему?** С одной стороны, это **устойчивое выражение** и его можно заменить наречием ***молча.***  Да и  Розенталь допускает обособление не только одиночного деепричастия, но и деепричастного оборота тоже, если он "тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания".

С другой стороны, именно этот оборот   **сложно сделать смысловым центром** и переместить на него логическое ударение (тогда сочетание сказуемое + оборот нужно читать в одну фразу, без паузы). **Поэтому мы видим, что во всех примерах из Нацкорпуса оборот обособляется.**

Можно предположить, что это связано с более сложной структурой оборота — **наличием усилительной частицы НИ.**

Остается единственная возможность не быть обособленным — это **вписаться в другой обособленный оборот** (причастный или деепричастный), но такое предложение сложно даже придумать, например: *Таким он и запомнился мне, промолчавшим весь вечер и **ушедшим не сказав ни слова**.*

Весь этот материал можно прочитать у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

4) Примеры

Как-то неловко уезжать, **не сказав ни слова.** [Людмила Уварова. Одинокий с собакой снимет комнату // Библиотека «Огонек», 1990]

На каждой было одно и то же: кто-то долго дышал, а потом клал трубку, **не сказав ни слова**. [Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001]

Артем непонимающе уставился на него, **не говоря ни слова**. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

Катерина с размаху швырнула в портфель телефон и вышла, **не говоря ни слова.** [Татьяна Устинова. Персональный ангел (2002)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

О словах ***наверное*** и ***наверно***

В словарной статье эти слова обозначены как полные синонимы, но в реальности это не совсем так, если судить по Нацкорпусу. Скорее всего, ситуация следующая.

Вводное слово  мы произносим как ***наверно***, но на письме чаще пишем ***наверное***. Причем форма ***наверно***  в основном употребляется на форумах, то есть ее можно было бы отнести **к разговорной**, в то время как ***наверное*** – это **книжная и нейтральная** формы.

Что касается **наречия,** то это скорее **книжное выражение**, поэтому преимущественно используется слово  ***наверное*** (*он знал это наверное*). Форма ***наверно*** в значении наречия  (*знал наверно*)  встречается редко, да и то в основном  в старых текстах.

Примеры с наречием:

Но я знал **наверно**, что у него были знакомства… [Ф. М. Достоевский. Подросток (1875)]  А впрочем, он ничего **не знал наверное**. [И. С. Тургенев. Дым (1867)] И вот Чехов, писавший только то, что **знал наверное**… [Анатолий Найман. Рассказы о Анне Ахматовой (1986-1987)]

Comment: Нет, оно так не работает. Предположения так нельзя пояснять. При такой структуре поясняется, почему торопится: *Анна торопится: [почему торопится?] ей надо успеть на автобус.* А если исходный вариант, то: *Думаю, что Анна торопится: [почему думаю?] она ушла, не сказав ни слова.* Так во всех примерах Розенталя.

Answer (score 0):

Пунктуация в данном случае была выбрана верно, однако есть некоторые спорные моменты. Давайте по порядку:

1) "Наверное" всегда является вводным словом со значением возможности/неуверенности, однако его вариант без -е, входящей в суффикс, может быть как вводным словом, так и наречием образа действия. В нашем случае запятая ставится.

2) Двоеточие после "торопится " поставлено верно и обозначает раскрытие смысла с помощью бессоюзной связи. Интересно, что при перестановке данных частей будет использовано уже тире (плюс следует убрать собственное имя Анна). Его постановка, опять же, имеет определенный смысл, о чем я здесь указывать не буду (возникнут вопросы  — обращайтесь ко мне в комментарии).

3) Наиболее интересная часть, на мой взгляд. Здесь сочетание "не сказав ни слова" можно определить как равносильный образ "молча, безмолвно" (хотя не очень корректно доказывать принадлежность деепричастия/ДО с помощью другого деепричастия, пусть и близкого к наречию). Здесь же можно воспринять ДО прямо, то есть в значении "ничего не сказала", в результате чего запятая будет уместна. Отмечу, что, как правило, деепричастные обороты (ДО) не переходят в близкие по значению к наречиям сочетания, однако в данном случае это возможно за счёт характера устойчивости.

Comment: Насчёт "наверное" Вы немного напутали. "Наверно" и "наверное" полные синонимы, и то и другое может быть наречием.

Comment: По крайней мере, я ещё нигде не встречал сочетание, содержащее данное слово с -е

Comment: Обнаружил на просторах Интернета: "Наверное (наверно, наверняка) . Это слово может быть и наречием в значении ‘точно, несомненно, верно’, хотя такое его употребление считается устаревшим (Я знаю об этом наверное) , и вводным словом со значением ‘вероятно, по-видимому, по всей вероятности’ (Наверно, я все-таки поеду)".

Comment: Подобные вещи лучше смотреть в толковых словарях, а не в "этих ваших интернетах" :) Вот [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x), например. Некоторые словари отмечают наречные значения этих слов устаревшими, да. Но все словари считают оба слова полными синонимами.

Comment: А мне вот что кажется. В нейтральном и разговорном стиле  мы скорее  скажем "знаю точно", но если стиль чуть выше нейтрального,когда люди говорят о чем-то важном, сокровенном, то может использоваться наречие "наверное" Примеры:  А я знаю наверное, что мы были ангелами, там где-то, и здесь были, и от этого все помним… [Андрей Балдин.  (1997)]  Одно я знаю наверное ― если бы когда-нибудь Вы стали моей женой ― это было бы таким огромным счастьем, которого, вероятно, не выдержало бы мое усталое сердце. [Лидия Вертинская.  (2004)]

Comment: В принципе, использование того или иного слова зависит от манеры говорящего. Так, согласитесь, что разговорная речь не обязательно будет содержать сокращения либо стилистически нейтральные слова. Поэтому, как я считаю, от какого-либо человека мы можем услышать любое сочетание.

Comment: Хотя, как Вы подчеркнули, большинство таких сочетаний характерно для определенных ситуаций. Хотя есть и такие слова, употребляемых, я бы сказал, исключительно в некоторых стилях, например "верно".