# Нужна ли запятая после "не покидая убежища"?

Tags: пунктуация

Не покидая убежища(,) они были в безопасности.

Кажется, это деепричастие и должно обособляться, но по смыслу здесь не столько действие, сколько состояние. Нужна ли постановка запятой?

Comment: Обычный деепричастный оборот. Если вы хоть где-то в параграфах про деепричастия найдете слово "состояние", дайте знать, я пока не встречал.

Comment: Ну например "Деепричастие, утратившее глагольное значение". http://sdo.rea.ru/cde/rus/1/eumk/2/2_005.htm Можно встретить такой пример: "Студенты приобретают знания не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические задания. (Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, по содержанию тесно связаны со сказуемыми; можно сказать: не только на лекциях, но и на практических занятиях, поэтому не отделяются запятыми)". Если идти по аналогии, то в данном примере можно сказать: "В убежище они были в безопасности".

Comment: Там обоснования конечно слабенькие. "Можно сказать без ответа= и не дожидаясь ответа...". Можно всегда за уши притянуть и сказать. См, например https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452138.  Деепричастные обороты не сказав ни слова, не говоря ни слова обособляются практически всегда и в любой позиции. Стать обстоятельством образа действия у них, как правило, не получается, поэтому они обозначают добавочное действие.

Comment: Но конечно какая-то логика в ваших словах есть. Другой вопрос, что все, на сколько я понимаю, тупо ставят запятые и не заморачиваются. Если уж вводить правило пунктуации, то стоило бы упомянуть про частицы перед деепричастным оборотом. Практически во всех ваших примерах они стоят.

Comment: Здесь образ действия: *Были в безопасности каким образом? Не покидая убежища.*